# AWS S3 Hosted Website Redirect from index.html not working correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

When I visit a site of the form `www.example.com/index.html` on my AWS S3 hosted site, I expect to see the homepage. Instead I get redirected to `www.example.com//`

I have enabled S3 static website hosting and configured my index document as index.html

Can anybody help with what is going on here?

Comment: Straightforward maybe :) never seen that.  If you look at index.html in the bucket, in metadata, it doesn't have an `x-amz-website-redirect-location` setting, does it? (It shouldn't).  Also, the index document is just "index.html" and not "/index.html" -- right?

Comment: It seems to be working now but I can't seem to pin down what has changed. Whatever the problem was I think it was stuck in the cache of the Cloudflare CDN somewhere, which made it hard to diagnose (even though I disabled the CDN cache). On another note there was metadata on the index.html file which was redirecting to to the root of my domain, which caused an infinite loop (not to www.example.com// but to www.example.com/) Thanks for the tip on that one Michael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be down to dodgy routing rule:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>index.htm</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>/</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I achieved the routing I required by creating a file called index.htm and adding `x-amz-website-redirect-location` meta data to point to the root of the domain, thanks @michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable [S3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) and [configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html) you index document as index.html. Make sure you are accessing the endpoint website and not the S3 URL.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already taken that step and still not working - I have updated my question to reflect this.